# Remove Point to Site from Virtual Network Gateway

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-vpn

I have a Virtual Network Gateway that I created for Site-to-Site VPN, I ended up enabling Point-to-Site by using the "Point-to-Site Configuration" but this caused issues with my existing site-to-site VPN, but now I have no way of removing the point to site setup, I cant even remove the Address Pool.  Any help would be appreciated.

When trying to remove the address pool, but I get the following error:

> Failed to save virtual network gateway ''. Error: The VPN client
>   configuration specified for gateway [Gateway] has an invalid IP or
>   CIDR notation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error might occur if the address pool that you have configured for VPN client has an invalid IP or CIDR notation. It should be a private IP address range that does not overlap with the on-premises location that you connect from, or with the VNet that you want to connect to.

Just change the address pool to a valid address range, and save Point-to-Site Configuration. The error will disappear.

If you want to delete a P2S configuration after enabling it, you must first delete each resource that pertains to the virtual network gateway. In this case, you have to remove the virtual network gateway and recreate a virtual network gateway for S2S connection. Also, you can still use the old GatewaySubnet in the same virtual network. For more information, you can refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-delete-vnet-gateway-powershell#deletep2s).

Comment: Correct, I don't want a valid pool/address range, in fact I want to get rid of it as its causing issues with my Site-to-Site VPNs. I dont to remove the Virtual Network Gateway either, as that will cause all my existing VPN connections to break, on top of that when I create a new Gateway I will get a new IP address and will have to request all my VPNs be re-established

Comment: If so, I suggest leaving the current p2s configuration with less address range there without uploading the certificate. There is no extra [charge](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/vpn-gateway/) for p2s connection If no Outbound P2S VPN data transfers. Also, you can continue to configure P2S once you need to use it someday.